# External tools for Eve Online

Tags: eve-online

What tools do you suggest to use on the desktop (Windows) to help me with the game. I know there is an API that exposes a lot of information.
I was thinking that it would be nice to have a tool that would show me my expenses and sales on the market to be able to analyze it, maybe export to excel, etc.

Comment: I vote for community wiki because the up votes are purely based on preference and opinion.

Comment: I second that vote. External EVE tools change rapidly over time making this question and the answers out of date very quickly.

Answer (score 14):

The canonical example would have to be [EVEmon](http://evemon.battleclinic.com/). Not only does it let you monitor your skill queue from outside the game and notify you when training finishes, but it also has an excellent ship and item browser that lets you quickly look up the statistics on anything you're interested in as well as find out whether you have the necessary skills to use it.

Comment: It now also monitors Evemail.

Answer (score 13):

[Eve Fitting Tool](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EFT) is useful for planning your future ship builds. You can export it to Evemon to automatically generate an optimized learning plan as well.

An excellent resource for finding 3rd party tools is the [Third Party Tools category on EVElopedia](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Category:Third_Party_Tools)

Comment: Now that CCP got rid of the learning skills, optimization of learning plans is no longer necessary. But Evemon will still generate a learning plan for your desired ship and fitting.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [Eve Commander](http://www.eve-commander.com/). It's not an application, but rather a webapp that manages all kinds of information for you.

Great interface, lots of useful stuff, very responsive developer.

It's not free, but paid for with in-game money. The prices are very reasonable, it was easily affordable and worth the money even for me as an Eve newbie.

Comment: +1 - the only real thing it's missing is skill planning - other than that it's wonderful (I have it bookmarked on my phone as it's better than any app I've tried).

Comment: It's no EVEMon, that's for sure, but doesn't it at least show your list of skills and your learning queue? No planning features, though.

Comment: Its actually been shut down now.

Comment: @GWLlosa Indeed, how sad. :(

Answer (score 2):

I use these: ( link with URLs http://eve.nako.us/tools/external-tools-for-eve-onine )

**EVEMon** - EVEMon is a lightweight, easy-to-use standalone Windows application designed to assist you in keeping track of your EVE Online character progression.

**EveHQ**
EveHQ is an extensible character application for use in conjunction with Eve-Online.Initially starting out as a character monitor and skill planner, EveHQ adopted a plug-in system where additional modules could be created independently of the main application which would extend the functionality of the program as a whole.

**EFT** - EVE Fitting Tool

**Wormhole Thingie** - Shows some useful info on wormholes and w-space systems.

**EVE Asset Manager**

**MyPOS**

**Eve-Metrics** Market upoader

**Eve-central** Upload Utility

**2D Maps**, PDF

**DOTLAN Eve Maps**

**EVEMap** is an out of game map of the EVE universe.

Comment: Summary posts don't work well on StackExchange, because it breaks the ranking and ordering by upvotes. Just FYI why I'm not upvoting that. Create a separate answer for e.g. the EVEMap, which is quite awesome (if it's the PDF that I remember).

Comment: @Cort Au contraire. This is what we prefer on this site.

Comment: @ArdaXi Yeah, my comment was mostly pre the strategy change regarding summarising posts on SE. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using http://eve.grismar.net/explorer/index.php quite often to find stuff in EVE. Most of the time I am looking for a new agent for a certain corp. Most other tools don't let me specify as much conditions to limit what is show to me.

I can i.e. say "I want a agent for Federation Navy that provides lvl 4 missions, mostly kill missions, resides in 0.5+ systems, and is available with my standings."

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [EVEHQ](http://www.evehq.net/), it covers most of the information exposed by the API.

Comment: Battleclininc are discontinuing EVEHQ last time I looked